# Using the Facebook Graph API, how do I get the user's networks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know what networks the user is in...like their high school, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522830/how-to-get-users-network-information-using-facebook-graph-api-php

Comment: That question doesn't ask about the Graph API.

Comment: Umm.. The title of the other question is "How to get user's network information using Facebook Graph API?" Either way, the answer there gives the same answer I could find.  Specifically, this isn't availalble through the graph api and you have to use FQL to get the data.  Also this http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=61053 supports that as the only method available.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question is correct, there's no support in Graph for querying a user's network. It's only available via FQL[Affiliations]